# a python library that accepts some text, and replaces phone numbers, names, and so on with tokens

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyparsing

I need a python library that accepts some text, and replaces phone numbers, names, and so on with tokens. Example:

Input: Please call Robert on 0430013454 to discuss this further.

Output: Please call *NAME* on *PHONE* to discuss this further.

In other words I need to take a sentence, any sentence, then the program will be run on that sentence and remove anything that looks like a name, phone number or any other identifier, and replace it with a token I.E *NAME*, *PHONE NUMBER* So that token would just be text to replace the info so that it is no longer displayed.

Must be python 2.7 compatible. Would anybody know how this would be done?

Cheers!

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I don't really understand. Do you just want to replace the name and the number with `' '`? What do you mean by "tokens"?

Comment: Who would upvote such a clearly off topic question?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking.

Comment: "and so on..." So, you want a library that guesses what you want?

Comment: Sorry ill rewrite the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure about name recognition. However, if you know the names that you would be looking for it would be easy. You could have a list of all of the names that you're looking for and check to see if each one is in the string and if so just use `string.replace`. If the names are random you could maybe look into NLTK I think they might have some name entity recognition. I really don't know anything about it though...

But as for phone numbers, that's easy. You can split the string into a list and check to see if any element consists of numbers. You could even check the length to make sure it's 10 digits (i'm assuming all numbers will be 10 based on your example).

Something like this...

```
example_input = 'Please call Robert on 0430013454 to discuss this further.'

new_list = example_input.split(' ')

for word in new_list:
    if word.isdigit():
        pos = new_list.index(word)
        new_list[pos] = 'PHONE'

example_output = ' '.join(new_list)

print example_output
```

This would be the output: `'Please call Robert on PHONE to discuss this further'`

The if statement would be something like `if word.isdigit() and len(word) == 10:` if you wanted to make sure the length of the digits is 10.

Answer (score 1):

As Harrison pointed out, nltk has named entity recognition, which is what you want for this task. [Here](https://gist.github.com/onyxfish/322906) is a good sample to get you started.

From the site:

```
import nltk 

sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
tokenized_sentences =      [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sentences]
tagged_sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sentence) for sentence in tokenized_sentences]
chunked_sentences = nltk.ne_chunk_sents(tagged_sentences, binary=True)

def extract_entity_names(t):
    entity_names = []

    if hasattr(t, 'label') and t.label:
        if t.label() == 'NE':
            entity_names.append(' '.join([child[0] for child in t]))
        else:
            for child in t:
                entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(child))

    return entity_names

entity_names = []
for tree in chunked_sentences:
    # Print results per sentence
    # print extract_entity_names(tree)

    entity_names.extend(extract_entity_names(tree))

# Print all entity names
#print entity_names

# Print unique entity names
print set(entity_names)
```